# Deadlock in Master-Slave model with MPI

Tags: c++, synchronization, mpi, master-slave

I am trying to implement master/slave model with MPI, but I have a slight problem.

What I want to do is, slaves should wait for orders from master, they shouldn't work until master sends an order. Master should send an order at the same time to all slaves, wait for all slaves to finish the order, and then send orders to all slaves at the same time again.

For example, I have 3 processors (1 master, 2 slaves), I send orders to slaves twice and I want to print:

```
Master initialization done.
Master sends order to slave 1
Master sends order to slave 2
Slave 1 got the order from master
Slave 2 got the order from master
Master got response from Slave 1
Master got response from Slave 2
_________________________________
Master sends order to slave 1
Master sends order to slave 2
Slave 1 got the order from master
Slave 2 got the order from master
Master got response from Slave 1
Master got response from Slave 2
All done.
```

Here's what I have done so far.

```
int count = 0;
int number;
if (procnum == 0) {
    // initialize master, slaves shouldn't be working until this ends
    std::cout << "Master initialization done." << endl;
    while (count < 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i < numprocesses; i++) {
            number = i * 2;
            std::cout << "Master sends order to slave " << i << endl;
            MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            std::cout << "Master got response from Slave " << i << endl;
        }
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << "All done" << endl;
} else {
    int received;
    MPI_Recv(&received, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    std::cout << "Slave " << procnum << " got the order from master" << endl;
    MPI_Send(&received, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

But I am getting this:

```
Master initialization done.
Master sends order to slave 1
Slave 1 got the order from master
Master got response from Slave 1
Master sends order to slave 2
Slave 2 got the order from master
Master got response from Slave 2
Master sends order to slave 1
```

Then it gets stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you writing "std::cout << "All done" << endl;" inbetween if & else??

Comment: @Nishant I had problem with formatting when copy pasting, it's actually written correctly in the program. I'm editing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
```

EDIT: it's OK because `size` is 3 (includes the server)

About the sequence: MPI_Send and MPI_Recv are blocking calls, so the output is as expected (?).

If the master is blocked on the 2nd round, it's because the slave is not responding. The `while (count < 2)` loop should wrap both master and slave.

Comment: No, I can send orders to both of them. Problem is I can't do it for the second time.

Comment: ah no, size is 3 because 0 is master. Read my output carefully, slave 2 gets orders, no problem with that.

Comment: As I have said, if it is master process, it should send orders to slaves at the same time, wait for all slaves to give response, send orders again, wait again, and then print "All done". Slaves should just print something.

Comment: I mean, look at the answer, the if...else seems broken. Looks like a copy/paste error.

Comment: Sorry about it, I updated the question. I had a problem with formatting so somehow I deleted some parts.

Comment: I see. But can't understand why it would not respond. Any idea?

Comment: Just that ? So it only responds once ...?

Comment: Ok, got it this time. Now master doesn't wait for all responses to give orders for the second time. How can I make it wait?

Comment: send 1rst orders => non-blocking waits (threads ?) on both slaves until all have responded => 2nd orders => ...